# In Kotlin, how to check List<Any> contains one or another dataclass?

Tags: list, kotlin

I have two data classes

```
    data class Card(val code: String?, val caption: String?, val icon: String?)
    data class Currency(val code: String?, val caption: String?, val descr: String?)
```

which are organized into lists: `List<Card> and List<Currency>` which I use as parameters when calling a one function. The parameter type is defined as `List<Any>`. How inside a class or function I can determine the type of data?
Is that list of Card or list of Currency?

This is for Android application on Kotlin

```
class SpinnerAdapter(val context: Context, var name: List<Any>): BaseAdapter() {
    init {
        if (name.contains(Card)) { //is list of Card?

        }
    }
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
   ...
```

Comment: What guarantee is there that `name` won't contain both `Card` and `Currency` instances? For that matter, what guarantee is there that no other types will be present?

Comment: The guarantee is that I use the spinner only in certain places

Comment: So long as this is internal code you have absolute control over, then the given answer is one approach. Basically, check to see if an element in the list is an instance of `Card` or `Currency`; this is done with `is` in Kotlin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you can use the cool when feature here that kotlin provides.
for example:

```
class SpinnerAdapter(var name: List<Any>) {
init {
    when(name.first()){
        is Card -> {
            //  do something
        }

        is Currency -> {
            //  do something
        }

        else -> // do something
    }
}
```

}

this solution rely on that the list of any can have either all card or all currency. if list can hold mixed items, you should run a for loop before and let the when block to decide the flow.

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Amazia works but you could improve it by implementing a sealed class like so:

```
sealed class PaymentMethod {
    abstract val code: String?
    abstract val caption: String?

    data class Card(override val code: String?, override val caption: String?, val icon: String?) : PaymentMethod
    data class Currency(override val code: String?, override val caption: String?, val descr: String?) : PaymentMethod
}
```

More information about sealed classes in Kotlin: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html

this allows you to do an exhaustive when clause over your List of PaymentMethods like so (No need for else branch):

```
class SpinnerAdapter(var name: List<PaymentMethod>) {
init {
    when(name.first()){
        is Card -> {
            //  do something
        }

        is Currency -> {
            //  do something
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use this exhaustive when in a stream if you'd like:

```
class SpinnerAdapter(var name: List<PaymentMethod>) {
init {
    name.map{ 
        when(name.first()){
            is Card -> {
                //  do something
            }
            is Currency -> {
                //  do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```